# Firebase read latest data from database

Tags: unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to firebase realtime database. I have constructed my game however, I have some concerns.

1. I am Using a root `Players` and I am planning to store couple of data for each player. Ex: `Players/User ID/[level, score, XP, etc..]`. I am using push method, should I consider transaction? As far as I understood, since only 1 player is going to write his own data, push seems to be enough? Am I right?
2. For the database, I only want to update player data (after completion of each game, data will be updated), so still do I need key? To be honest, for my case, I still did not understand the need of key :) What happens, if I do not use it, since there is only 1 set of data per player?
3. If the key is necessary (although I still did not understand :)), how should I read the latest data from structure (`childUpdates["/Players/" + uid + "/" + key]`)? Because, the key is specific and I do not know it when retrieving data, how can I use it for retrieving data?

[image: My Database]

[image]

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Can you please paste the database data. How its Currently Stored for your game so that we can have a better understanding.

Comment: I added. I have realized that, I asked it longly but simply, how can I just retrieve the latest data per player and update it accordingly? For this do I need any transaction or key implementation? :)

Comment: Which platform are you using to work with Firebase? Android, IOS or Web(javascript)??

Comment: For Android. I am using Unity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transactions are useful when multiple users are updating the same data at almost the same time. If only a single user will be updating the data, you don't need to use a transaction.

When you call `Push()` on a location, Firebase automatically generates a new unique child nodes under that location. If you only want to store one set of properties (`level`, `score`, etc) for each player, you should not call push, but instead call `SetValueAsync()` directly on the location.

Comment: Thanks Frank, not it makes much sense to me :) So, I need to use something like below? mDatabaseRef.Child("users").Child(userId).Child("username").SetValueAsync(name); and GetValueAsync similar to read data?

Comment: Yup. If you're having problems making it work, it's a lot easier for us to help if we can see what you've already done. See[how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).